# Django upload video with automatic thumbnails generation

Tags: python, django, video, file-upload, django-forms

I want to upload mp4 and mov videos to my django website with automatic thumbnail generation.
Thumbnails can be jpg or png that will save in ImageField and video to FileField.

```
thumbnail = models.ImageField()
video = models.FileField()
```

I am using Python 3.6.3, Django 1.11.8 and dropzone.

Please suggest me how to create a video upload page similar to youtube.

Is there any opensource plugin available to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org).

```
import subprocess

video_path = '/tmp/video.mov'
image_path = '/tmp/video.jpg'
time = '00:00:00.000'

subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', video_path, '-ss', time, '-vframes', '1', image_path])
```

That'll take 1 frame at 00:00:00.000 of your video and store it as an image.

Comment: my doubt is where to use this code. should we use it in views.py , if yes then how, or should we use it in html page or in models.py .

Comment: @SandipKumar as that process should take time to run, better to have it on an async process - ie. have it on the `model.save()` method or a signal calling a delayed celery task

Comment: As Andre suggested. Open your models.py, then in the class of the object you want to represent create a new method called `def save(self,*args,**kwargs): 
//what you want then
super().save(*args,**kwargs)`